# C: free(): invalid next size (fast) 0x0167b230

Tags: c

when i run my programm i always get: **free(): invalid next size (fast) 0x0167b230**.

I think that something is not right at memory allocate but i dont know what.

```
    float* Average;
    float* toStringAverage;

    int* arraySecondSpace;
    int* A;

    char* tempLastName;
    char* tempNames;
    char* pend;
    char** Names;
    char** lastName;
```

That's my variables.

```
    Average = (float *) calloc(studentsCounter, sizeof(float));
    A = (int *) malloc(studentsCounter * sizeof(int));
    arraySecondSpace = (int *) malloc(studentsCounter * sizeof(int));
    tempNames = (char *) malloc(studentsCounter * sizeof(char));
    tempLastName = (char *) malloc(studentsCounter * sizeof(char));
    toStringAverage = (float *) malloc(studentsCounter * sizeof(float));

    lastName = (char **) malloc(studentsCounter * sizeof(char *));
    for(i = 0; i < studentsCounter; i++)
        lastName[i] = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));

    Names = (char **) malloc(studentsCounter * sizeof(char *));
    for(i = 0; i < studentsCounter; i++)
        Names[i] = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
```

I allocate memory and i make some stuffs.

```
    free(Average);
    free(A);
    free(arraySecondSpace);
    free(tempNames);
    free(tempLastName);
    free(toStringAverage);

    for (i = 0; i < studentsCounter; i++)
        free (lastName[i]);

    free(lastName);

    for (i = 0; i < studentsCounter; i++)
        free (Names[i]);

    free(Names);
```

And i free my memory.

Comment: One of the variables probably got changed at some point, perhaps through the invocation of undefined behaviour. If so, `-fsanitize=address` might help

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  The bug is likely to be in the code where you actually write to these blocks of memory, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Likely a memory corruption and root cause may be in code that is not shown.

Comment: @user3121023 I tried it, tha same error

Comment: The error message means your code wrote outside the bounds of what was allocated.  If you can, use [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org) to identify the problem. Otherwise, scrutinize your code for where you write out of bounds.

Comment: I will suggest use valgrind to test your program, it will show where your allocated memory corruption is happening follow this link and test your program https://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html